# How to blacklist a package?

Tags: package

I am using `company-mode` for completion purposes. But somehow, some package always draws in `auto-complete` as well, which collides with `company-mode`, since both offer a popup with completion candidates. I want to blacklist `auto-complete`, since I do not need it. How can I do that? I know there is a variable `package-pinned-package`, but I cannot see how to blacklist a package — maybe by using an invalid archive?

Comment: Note that there is no collision per se.  For `autocomplete-mode` to be a problem, it must be enabled first, same goes for `company-mode`.

Comment: For some reason, it gets enabled without me doing any customizations.

Comment: If it is a requirement of another package then it has to be installed, but it should be possible to not have `autocomplete` be active in any buffer where `company-mode` is active. Perhaps you need to manually disable `autocomplete` in the `*mode-hook` of any affected major modes?

Comment: I suggest you to find out what does.  Either it's you (and something in your init file, a possibility that has become a lot more probable since the acceptance of starter kits) or another package (which is a bug).  Both bisection and searching your `~/.emacs.d` for something along the lines of `(auto-complete-mode)` would work.

Comment: Packages generally shouldn't enable auto-complete-mode for you (save some very specific circumstances). If you're 100%sure that you're not enabling it yourself, I suggest you file an issue in that package reporting this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how to blacklist the installation of a package. But it's easy to prevent it from *loading*. If you put `(provide 'auto-complete)` in your init file, then any package that tries to load `auto-complete` will be told that it's already loaded.

(More precisely, this takes care of libraries that load `auto-complete` in the normal way, with `require`. If there's any code that uses `load` directly (which would be unusual), [you need to put this in a separate file called `auto-complete.el`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20205).)

Of course, if the package requires `auto-complete`, it's probably because it'll use it. But maybe a package only declares autocomplete sources and has useful functionality otherwise. So you can make the part that you don't want a no-op. Depending on what the package does, you may need other similar definitions.

```
(provide 'auto-complete)
(defmacro ac-define-source (&rest ignored)
  "A no-op since I blacklist `auto-complete'.")
```

Answer (score 7):

What @Gilles wrote is the general answer I would have given also.

But note that using `provide` does *not* prevent code from loading the package. It prevents code from loading the package only by `require`. If code uses `load`, `load-library`, `load-file` etc. then this trick has no effect.

If you really need to prevent code from loading a given library, a better approach is to provide a proxy library that gets loaded in its stead. For example, in a directory that comes earlier in your `load-path`, add a phony `auto-complete.el` that does nothing except `(provide 'auto-complete)`.

That way, whenever code tries to load the library using `load` or `load-library` your proxy library will be loaded instead of the one you are avoiding.

However, if code uses `load-file` and provides the absolute address of the file of the library you are trying to avoid, then that file will be loaded. I don't see a good solution for that case (except to remove or replace that file).